# How to detect corrupted image files in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, png, jpeg

I'm looking for some generic library to check if downloaded images are not corrupted.

I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm which uses ImageMagick.

I can use `identify` from ImageMagick which will find totally broken images (the one I can't even open). But there are also partially broken images - for example jpeg file with a half of an image in grey and those are not marked as corrupted by gm.

How to check image for corruption in node.js?

Thanks!

Edit:

What I would like to detect are images that aren't downloaded completely. Similar effect you can achieve by cutting last n bytes of image.

I guess it is possible to detect it programmatically because identify commend in verbose mode returns:

```
identify: Premature end of JPEG file broken_example.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.
identify: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment broken_example.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.
```

Example (unfortunately imgur would chop off broken image, so I had to upload screenshot):

[Broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ml5J.png)

Comment: Are those images that can be identified as corrupt programmatically in the first place? Maybe upload an example..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited post

Comment: A photo of a mistake does not help us to fix the mistake (bad bytes)... Please use some free file-share site (like **http://www.mega.nz** ) and upload the files there. Or you can open file via **http://www.onlinehexeditor.com/** (copy only the blue mid-section ranging from 00 to 0f ) then paste those bytes values into **http://pastebin.com/** and share the links. Whichever method,  kindly upload the examples of **(1)** Totally broken and **(2)** Partially broken?

Comment: PS: If you're willing to try PHP (you have it installed?) instead of Node.js, then I'll try show you a possible solution. This would meaning using PHP the read bytes of file and check for the errors. Need just the 2 examples first to see what we are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

using :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-corrupted-jpeg

```js
var isCorrupted = require('is-corrupted-jpeg');
console.log(isCorrupted('./path/to/image/not-corrupted.jpg'));
//=> true
console.log(isCorrupted('./path/to/image/corrupted.jpg'));
//=> false
```